# "-" shown diff between sublime and IDEA

Tags: encoding, ide

I copy a code from a pdf . it is similar with "+-----+"

The strange thing is when it copied to Ultraedit or Textedit or Sublime (Mac notebook) the "-" would always not been shown.

```
By UE Hex mode, the binary is :C2 AD, and shown as a "A with a ^ above";
and if copied to IDEA, it would been shown correctly as "+-----+";
if in sublime ,it would disappear, just shown as "++".
```

But use javac to compile and run it ,two software would both print to file "-" at the same apperance.

The problem is :
Why same item copied to different software showned diff appearance? Is it the Software's coding setting diffs? but I checked IDEA and sublime and UE were all UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

The character UTF-8 encoded with `C2 AD` is a [soft hyphen](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00ad/index.htm) according to Unicode specification. A [soft hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen) should be used only inside a word for the purpose of breaking words across lines by inserting visible [hyphens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen).

Word processing applications like Microsoft Word do that. A soft hyphen can be inserted in MS Word by hitting <kbd>Strg+-</kbd> and should be used always instead of `-` (normal [hyphen](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/002d/index.htm)) on a word which needs to be broken at end of a line. When the line or the paragraph containing the line changes resulting in broken word no longer being at end of the line, the soft hyphen is no longer displayed and printed by the word processing application as hyphen.

The configured font defines how the soft hyphen character is displayed by a text editor like Sublime, Notepad++ or UltraEdit. Most fonts define this character without a glyph and so nothing is displayed on viewing a text with soft hyphen in a text editor.

IntelliJ IDEA uses either a different font than the other text editors or interprets a soft hyphen always or depending on context like a hyphen and map the character to U+002D.

The usage of soft hyphens between two plus signs is definitely a wrong usage of soft hyphens.